# Sending data to controller by Ajax

Tags: asp.net, .net, c, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

Usually we send data to controller by ajax like following::

```
 $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                url: "/Controller/MyAction",
                data: "{'Name':'" + id + "','Class':'" + cls + "'}",
                dataType: "json",
```

See I have to members to send to controller by two different parameters.
I want to send it as a list.

but What I want is to send a list to the controller in just one parameter. Is it possible but how can I achieve that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`JSON.stringify` is the key here.

Here is the code:

```
var myList = { List: [{ Name: "A", Class: "B" }, 
                            { Name: "C", Class: "D" }] };

$.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/{controller}/{action}',
        cache: false,
        data: JSON.stringify(myList),
        dataType: 'json', 
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
    });
```